# Save the output of a pandas groupby operation to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I would like to ask a question about Pandas groupby.
I am using ipython notebook (python3).

For example, there is a dataframe like this.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( { "Score" : ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A"] ,"Class":
["Physics", "Science", "Chemistry", "Biology", "History", "English"] } )
```

Then, I want to groupby with Score.

```
df1.groupby("Score")
```

I need a output file of this and I tried

```
df1.groupby("Score").to_csv("Score.txt",sep="\t")
```

but this does not work.
Does anyone know how to make output file?

Answer (score 6):

What you're asking makes no sense.  You may not realize it though.  `groupby` creates a staging area for which to perform aggregation or transformations across groups of data.  Like, if we wanted to count the number of observations for each group, that'd be an aggregation.

Because you thought that you could output as some table, I'm going to guess that you thought `groupby` actually grouped the rows together.  That isn't bad interpretation of the term if you had never seen it used before, even if it is incorrect.  The way to do that would be to sort using the method `sort_values`.

```
df1.sort_values('Score')

       Class Score
0    Physics     A
3    Biology     A
5    English     A
1    Science     B
4    History     B
2  Chemistry     C
```

If Score were something else that wasn't already ordered lexicographically, we could use the `categorical` type to handle it for us.

```
score = df1.Score.astype('category', categories=list('ABCDF'), ordered=True)
df1.assign(Score=score).sort_values('Score')

       Class Score
0    Physics     A
3    Biology     A
5    English     A
1    Science     B
4    History     B
2  Chemistry     C
```

Finally, you output the data to the file as you expected

```
df1.sort_values('Score').to_csv("Score.txt", sep="\t")
```

Comment: Nice explanation ~ :-)

Comment: The categories are a nice touch but their effect will probably be lost on OP... :(

Comment: I'm trying to think of future readers as well.  As a matter of fact, I'm thinking of going back and rewriting a ton of my answers.  I have 3,800.  There's a lot of opportunity to improve with better explanations or simply outdated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell what you want to groupby counts, means or others.

```
 df1.groupby("Score").count().to_csv('d.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution ,I think is close to what you want

```
df1=df1.reset_index()
df1=df1.groupby(['Score','index']).Class.apply(sum).to_frame()
df1

Out[102]: 
                 Class
Score index           
A     0        Physics
      3        Biology
      5        English
B     1        Science
      4        History
C     2      Chemistry
```